# FLUTTER: How to delete multiple documents using where clause in cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete the documents where the driverID is equivelant to the logged-in user ID. I am using the code below, and its not working.

```
      requestToJoinReference.where('driverID'==user.uid).getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
        for(DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.documents)
          {
            // ds.reference.delete();
            print(ds.reference);
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 7):

This is not the right syntax to use the where clause in firebase, what you are looking for is

```
 requestToJoinReference.where('driverID', isEqualTo: user.uid).getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
        for(DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.documents)
          {
            //ds.reference.delete();
            print(ds.reference);
          }
      });
```

Also, delete() is aysnc so you would have to make your forEach loop async as well

```
requestToJoinReference.where('driverID', isEqualTo: user.uid).getDocuments().then((snapshot) {
        for(DocumentSnapshot ds in snapshot.documents)async {
            await ds.reference.delete();
            print(ds.reference);
          }
      });
```

And, this is not the recommended way to perform multiple deletes, what you need is Batch write, Batch writes allows you to execute multiple write operations as a single batch that can contain any combination of set, update, or delete operations.

```
Future<void> batchDelete() {
  WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();

  return  requestToJoinReference.where('driverID', isEqualTo: user.uid).get().then((querySnapshot) {

    querySnapshot.documents.forEach((document) {
      batch.delete(document.reference);
    });

    return batch.commit();
  });
}
```

I would also recommend you to upgrade your dependencies to the lastest version and refer the [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#batch-write) documentation for syntax changes.